# Is there a way to change the configuration of the Typerocket editor?

Tags: wordpress, typerocket

I'm trying to add options in the Typerocket editor.

Like after the Header 1/2/3/4/5 options in the select, have an option for things like a button or a blockquote.

But I can't figure out how to even bind myself to the config of the Typerocket editor. Is there a way to do so, like you can do with the Wordpress editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to echo some javascript in the wp-admin page to change Typerocket.

```
echo "<script>
TypeRocket.redactorSettings = {
    buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','deleted',
    'unorderedlist','orderedlist','outdent','indent',
    'image','file','link','alignment','horizontalrule'];
}
</script>";
```